# Having trouble with bootstrap navbar

Tags: navbar, react-bootstrap

When I start my react app, the following error occurs:

./src/components/Navbar.js

```
>  Line 5:9:  Parsing error: Unexpected token  
>  3 | function Navbar() {  
>  4 |     return {  
>  5 |         <nav className="navbar">  
>    |         ^  
>  6 |         <a className="navbar-home" href="#">Navbar</a>
```

```
import React from 'react';

function Navbar() {
return {
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
<div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
</div>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
    </div>
    </nav>
}
}

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the snippet you provided, I'm pretty sure you are getting this error since you are returning your JSX wrapped in curly brackets:

```
return {
<nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  ...
</nav>
}
```

If you wrap your JSX in round-brackets it should fix this issue:

```
return (
<nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  ...
</nav>
)
```